# Replacing Names with Index From Separate File using Pandas

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I have a node and an edge list that look like this:

```
Id   Label   Type
1   fie      gnome
2   fou      giant
3   fim      gnome
4   fee      dwarf

Source   target  Weight
fie   fou   2
fie   fim   2
fou   fee   2
fee   fim   3
```

How would I replace the names in the source and target files with the indexes from the nodes file?

The final output should be:

```
Source target   Weight
1      2        2
1      3        2
2      4        2
4      3        3
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want the output to look like.  Do you want the first line of the second file to become `gnome giant 2`?

Comment: Thank you-- edited to add the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably build a `dict` from `nodes.Label` and `nodes.Id`, and then pass it either to `replace()` or to `applymap`.  For example:

```
>>> weight.stack().replace(dict(zip(nodes.Label, nodes.Id))).unstack()
  Source target Weight
0      1      2      2
1      1      3      2
2      2      4      2
3      4      3      3
>>> d = dict(zip(nodes.Label, nodes.Id))
>>> weight.applymap(lambda x: d.get(x,x))
   Source  target  Weight
0       1       2       2
1       1       3       2
2       2       4       2
3       4       3       3
```

---

Some explanation.  First, we start with the DataFrames:

```
>>> nodes
   Id Label   Type
0   1   fie  gnome
1   2   fou  giant
2   3   fim  gnome
3   4   fee  dwarf
>>> weight
  Source target  Weight
0    fie    fou       2
1    fie    fim       2
2    fou    fee       2
3    fee    fim       3
```

Then we make the `dict` we want to replace things with:

```
>>> d = dict(zip(nodes.Label, nodes.Id))
>>> d
{'fou': 2, 'fim': 3, 'fee': 4, 'fie': 1}
```

Unfortunately `.replace()` doesn't work like you think it might on a DataFrame, because it applies to rows and columns, not elements.  But we can `stack` and `unstack` to get around this:

```
>>> weight.stack()
0  Source    fie
   target    fou
   Weight      2
1  Source    fie
   target    fim
   Weight      2
2  Source    fou
   target    fee
   Weight      2
3  Source    fee
   target    fim
   Weight      3
dtype: object
>>> weight.stack().replace(d)
0  Source    1
   target    2
   Weight    2
1  Source    1
   target    3
   Weight    2
2  Source    2
   target    4
   Weight    2
3  Source    4
   target    3
   Weight    3
dtype: object
>>> weight.stack().replace(d).unstack()
  Source target Weight
0      1      2      2
1      1      3      2
2      2      4      2
3      4      3      3
```

Or, alternatively, we can just use a `lambda` and `applymap`.  Dictionaries have a `get` method which accepts a default parameter, so `somedict.get(k, 'default value goes here')` will look the key `k` up, return the corresponding value if the key is found, and otherwise return the second parameter.  So `d.get(x, x)` will either change `x` to the corresponding value in the dictionary or return `x` and leave it alone.  Thus:

```
>>> weight.applymap(lambda x: d.get(x,x))
   Source  target  Weight
0       1       2       2
1       1       3       2
2       2       4       2
3       4       3       3
```

PS: the same dict-based approach will work if you only want to apply the replace to certain columns, but you'd have to restrict the application.  For example, if you wanted to go the other way, you probably wouldn't want the `2` in the weight column to become `fou`.

Comment: Interesting! It seems like the stacking/unstacking would be a bit expensive. Is the second way faster?

Comment: stacking and unstacking isn't as slow as you might think, but at least in this case it's slower.  The `applymap` approach consistently seems a factor of 2 or so faster in my tests, but YMMV, and I'd be pretty surprised if this were a bottleneck anyhow.

Comment: Oddly, neither worked. The replace method only replaced the first column.

Comment: I find that very surprising.  Could you find a minimal example for which it doesn't work and post the `.to_dict()`?  One possibility is that there's whitespace in one column not present in another, and so the replace isn't working because there's not actually a match.

Comment: Hmm... white space is possible.. Let me try.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot, I wasn't saving the results. Yes, it does work! Big thank you!